# Access Bootstrap CSS sheets locally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Boostrap CSS sheets for my sites.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

When I get those files and save as a local css file then access, they don't work. How can I store those css files in my site and access ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download the entire distribution package from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download).

Click the download button.

The package includes the CSS files, the JS files and the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and download the distribution. You'll find all files in it, then just move them to your website folder, and add them.

Answer (score 1):

go to the  [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) page and download

below is how you link it if the downloaded `bootstrap.min.css` is copied in `stylesheets` folder of your project

```
<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```